# non-free module for Opencv 3.3.0 windows

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, eclipse-cdt

I'm using eclipse neon in windows. I want to use surf in C++ and I'm unable to find a solution. I currently have opencv 3.3.0 for which I made the eclipse build using cmake. Do I really need non-free module or is there another way? And how can I add non-free module?

Comment: There is no nonfree module from OpenCV 3.x.x. it is moved to the Contrib Module. You can find all the contrib module here!https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib

Comment: The problem that I'm facing is that building contrib using cmake is failing.

Comment: Then I would suggest posting the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/07/16/where-did-sift-and-surf-go-in-opencv-3/) but in summary SURF has been moved to the contrib module in OpenCV3.0

> SIFT and SURF are examples of algorithms that OpenCV calls “non-free” modules. These algorithms are patented by their respective creators, and while they are free to use in academic and research settings, you should technically be obtaining a license/permission from the creators if you are using them in a commercial (i.e. for-profit) application.
>
> With OpenCV 3 came a big push to move many of these “non-free” modules out of the default OpenCV install and into the opencv_contrib package. The opencv_contrib  packages contains implementations of algorithms that are either patented or in experimental development.

[here](https://gist.github.com/SSARCandy/fc960d8905330ac695e71e3f3807ce3d) is a tutorial on how to install the contrib library using cmake which does not happen by default.

Comment: The problem that I'm facing is that building contrib using cmake is failing.

Answer (score 0):

According to SURF author [Herbert Bay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2707207/herbert-bay) , he has published the original source code to  https://github.com/herbertbay/SURF . It should be more robust than the OpenCV version. So you don't need non free module anymore to work with SURF